# Ethereumjs: How to save the blockchain / state

Tags: blockchain, ethereumjs, leveldb

Ethereumjs noob here. Using the code below, I'm able to create a new blockchain and add blocks to it. But the blocks are not being saved to the database.

```
var blockdb = levelup("./blockdb", {createIfMissing: true});
var blockchain = new Blockchain({"blockDB": blockdb, "validate": false})

blockchain.getHead(function (err, head) {

    var myblock = blockFromRpc(blockdata);

    blockchain.putBlock(myblock, function(a,b) {
        ...
    })

})
```

This seems to work fine. But when I try reloading the blockchain with the same DB's as above, it's empty. How do I save the blockchain with the added blocks?